# How to convert lists of tuples in a list to a 1-D array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I have a multidimensional list of tuples of different sizes in a list and I am trying to convert that to a 1-D array, but I keep getting an error. If my list looks like:

```
rain2 = [[(298.0, 345.0, 412.0)], [(421.0, 203.0)], [(491.0,)]]
```

How do I convert that to a 1-D array?
I tried:

```
chain = np.asarray(rain2, dtype=float)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output? What numpy version are you using? It works for me.

Comment: I can verify, too......@RockyLi

Comment: @Idlehands fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy-ravel) along with [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to convert it to 1D array:

```
import numpy as np

rain2 = [[(298.0, 345.0, 412.0)], [(421.0, 203.0)], [(491.0)]]
chain = np.hstack(np.ravel(rain2))
print(chain)
```

Output:

```
[298. 345. 412. 421. 203. 491.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check this below:

`np.reshape(chain, (chain.size,1))`